# Blank page after running build on the react app and errors on the console

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React JS. I was deploying my React App that I created using `create-react-app` on netlify. The build was successful but on checking the link https://schotrix.netlify.app/, it was showing a blank page and errors on the console. So i decided to check again on my localhost by running `npm run build` I realized it's the same problem.

What could these errors mean and how can I solve them?
[picture to the error on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD0aF.jpg)

> react-dom.production.min.js:216
> Error
> at i (index.tsx:19:20)
> at index.tsx:776:5
> at react.production.min.js:19:66
> at react.production.min.js:17:388
> at S (react.production.min.js:16:230)
> at C (react.production.min.js:17:355)
> at Object.forEach (react.production.min.js:19:49)
> at j (index.tsx:760:3)
> at index.tsx:791:24
> at react.production.min.js:19:66
> su @ react-dom.production.min.js:216
> n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:216
> ho @ react-dom.production.min.js:131
> yu @ react-dom.production.min.js:220
> Ac @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
> t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
> qa @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
> Nc @ react-dom.production.min.js:252
> gc @ react-dom.production.min.js:243
> vc @ react-dom.production.min.js:237
> el @ react-dom.production.min.js:285
> (anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:289
> jc @ react-dom.production.min.js:244
> il @ react-dom.production.min.js:289
> t.render @ react-dom.production.min.js:296
> 287 @ index.js:6
> i @ (index):1
> t @ (index):1
> r @ (index):1
> (anonymous) @ main.b32d759b.chunk.js:1
> index.tsx:19
> Uncaught Error
> at i (index.tsx:19:20)
> at index.tsx:776:5
> at react.production.min.js:19:66
> at react.production.min.js:17:388
> at S (react.production.min.js:16:230)
> at C (react.production.min.js:17:355)
> at Object.forEach (react.production.min.js:19:49)
> at j (index.tsx:760:3)
> at index.tsx:791:24
> at react.production.min.js:19:66

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had to run `npm start` inorder to find out what exactly the error is and for my case the error was

```js
Error: [Users] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

because i was accessing the component like this

```js
<Route path="/users" ><Users/></Route>
```

instead of this

```js
<Route path="/users" element={<Users/>}/>
```